# Drupal 8 - slide show exposing image alt text as a caption

Tags: image, view, drupal-8

I have a block view which shows the image caroseul - but I want to expose the image alt text and use it as a caption

[image]

[image]

what would be the replacement pattern?

{{file:field_alt_text}}?

{{field_images_alt_text}} ?

Answer (score 2):

Did you click on the "Replacement Patterns" dropdown? It should be something like {{ field_image__alt }}.

Comment: It only showed basic examples - I didn't see a data dictionary of possible terms - I remember sometimes I had to expose an image field above - in order to gain access to other attributes

Comment: ok --- I had to create another image filed - exclude it from display - and rewrite its output - and then I used a custom global field to pick it up